# create sequence of months and days with no year

Tags: r, datetime, xts, tidyverse, lubridate

Good afternoon. I am attempting to make a sequence of month-day dates. The desired result would be October 1st through December 31st. I think the code is simple enough to show my intent, but is flawed in its logic. Thanks very much for any help here.

```
start <- as.Date("10/1", "m%-d%")
end <- as.Date("12/31", "m%-d%")

seq(start, end, by = "1 Day")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a date sequence (any year would work, no need to be 2001 in my example), and then use the `format` function.

```
format(seq.Date(as.Date("2001-10-31"), as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = 1),
         format = "%m-%d")
# [1] "10-31" "11-01" "11-02" "11-03" "11-04" "11-05" "11-06" "11-07" "11-08" "11-09" "11-10"
# [12] "11-11" "11-12" "11-13" "11-14" "11-15" "11-16" "11-17" "11-18" "11-19" "11-20" "11-21"
# [23] "11-22" "11-23" "11-24" "11-25" "11-26" "11-27" "11-28" "11-29" "11-30" "12-01" "12-02"
# [34] "12-03" "12-04" "12-05" "12-06" "12-07" "12-08" "12-09" "12-10" "12-11" "12-12" "12-13"
# [45] "12-14" "12-15" "12-16" "12-17" "12-18" "12-19" "12-20" "12-21" "12-22" "12-23" "12-24"
# [56] "12-25" "12-26" "12-27" "12-28" "12-29" "12-30" "12-31"
```

Comment: Thank you! very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively with `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

format( seq(ymd('2018-10-01'),ymd('2018-12-31'),by='days'), "%m-%d" )
[1] "10-01" "10-02" "10-03" "10-04" "10-05" "10-06" "10-07" "10-08" "10-09" 
...etc to "12-31"
```